# Error con tabla dinámica

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabla-dinámica

**Hola!!!** Estoy trabajando con una tabla dinámica para agregar/eliminar relaciones de acceso a los roles de mi aplicación.  Todo funciona bien al agregar, pero al eliminar una fila de la tabla dinámica (en mi vista) me lanza el siguiente error en javascript:
       [Violation] 'click' handler took 6331ms javascript
Todos los coemntarios dicen que es un bug de chrome versión 58, 56, etc pero mi versión es la 68 y el error sigue ahí.
Les comparto mi código (ya probé sustituyendo el checkbox por button y el error sigue)

```
<div class="box box-success" style="padding:30px;">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Cadena de Ventas/Rol</div>
</div>
    <div class="row" id="mydiv">
        <div class="card card-warning">
            {!! Form::open(array('url' => '', 'method' => 'POST'))!!}
              {!! Form::hidden('id_role', $id_role, ['id' => 'id_role'] )!!}
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Canal:</label>
                    {!! Form::select('id_canal',  [''=>'::Seleccione::']+$canales,  NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'id_canal', 'required' ]   )!!}    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Cadena Ventas:</label>
                    {!! Form::select('id_cadena_venta', $cadena_ventas,  NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'id_cadena_venta', 'required'])!!}    
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="add-row ">Agregar</button>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover" id="tabla">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Seleccione</th>
                            <th>Canal</th>
                            <th>Cadena Ventas</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    //dd($cadena_roles);
                    ?>
                        @foreach ($cadena_roles as $object)

                        <tr > 
                        <td><input type='checkbox' value="{{ $object->id_cadena_roles }}" name='record' id="{{ $object->id_cadena_roles }}"></td>
                            <!-- <td><input type='checkbox' value="{{ $object->id_cadena_venta }}" name='record'></td> -->
                            <td>{{ $object->des_canal }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $object->des_cadena_venta }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="delete-row">Borrar</button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#id_canal').change(function(){
    var id_canal = $(this).val();
    var id_rol = $("#id_role").val();
    var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "selectEditAjax",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {id_canal:id_canal, id_rol:id_rol, _token:token},
        success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html('');
            $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html(data.options);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    //$('#mydiv').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled','disabled');

    var arrayvalores = []; 
    var id_rol = $("#id_role").val();
    var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var name = $("#id_canal option:selected").text();
        var email = $("#id_cadena_venta option:selected").text();
        var id_canal = $("#id_canal").val();
        var id_cadena_venta = $("#id_cadena_venta").val();

        //alert(arrayvalores+ "id rol "+id_rol+" cadena venta "+id_cadena_venta_+" token "+token);
        $.ajax({
            url: "storeEditAjax",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {id_rol:id_rol, id_cadena_venta:id_cadena_venta, _token:token},
            success: function(data) {


                 //alert(data);   

                var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' value="+data+" name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
                //arrayvalores.push(id_cadena_venta_);
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
                //recargar el combo de cadenas, eliminando la que ya se guardó
                $.ajax({
                    url: "selectEditAjax",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id_canal:id_canal, id_rol:id_rol, _token:token},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html('');
                        $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html(data.options);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){

        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //alert($(this).val());

                var id_cadena_roles = $(this).val();
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                //alert("id "+id_cadena_venta+" id rol "+id_rol);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "deleteEditAjax",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id_cadena_roles:id_cadena_roles, _token:token},
                    success: function(data) {

                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                    }
                });   
                //recargar el combo de cadenas, eliminando la que ya se guardó
                $.ajax({
                    url: "selectEditAjax",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id_canal:id_canal, id_rol:id_rol, _token:token},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html('');
                        $("select[name='id_cadena_venta'").html(data.options);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
});    


 </script>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Virginia.
Este tipo de mensajes tratan de alertarte como desarrollador y ayudarte a mejorar tu sentencia de instrucciones. En este caso chrome trata de advertirte que un evento 'click' tardo demasiado '6XXX ms' y que considera excesivo.

Seguramente por la iteración .each que ejecutas cada vez que realizar 'click' en el elemento '.delete-row'

Aún así, ¿Qué no funciona como esperas? ¿No se eliminan los elementos?

Comment: Si se eliminan, pero se queda "colgado" unos segundos.  Traté de resolverlo, eliminando los checkbox y en su lugar colocándole un botón "eliminar" a cada fila, pero el error sigue

Answer (score 0):

Por supuesto, el evento delete-row click es demasiado lento de esa manera... Te recomiendo otro enfoque totalmente distinto...

Ahora mismo se invocan dos ajax (deleteEditAjax y selectEditAjax) por cada elemento que quieres borrar...

Un cambio importante sería construirte un array con los elementos que quieres borrar, y luego hacer una sola vez, las llamadas a tus dos ajax...

Aquí te crearías ese array de los seleccionados...

```
var seleccionados = [];
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
           seleccionados.push($(this).val());
}
```

Y con eso se acabaron tus bucles... Ahora en los ajax's pasas el array seleccionados en vez de un sólo valor como tenías antes...

```
data: {seleccionados:seleccionados, _token:token},
```

Solo queda, cambios en la url: deleteEditAjax y selectEditAjax, ya que, como lo tienes ahora, aparte del token que reciben, esperaban un solo elemento a borrar, y ahora llega un array...

Un saludo